# Form data being posted but not being sent with php mail()

Tags: forms, post, php

I am creating a job application form which has a drop down box that the user can select a city from and continue filling out the form. The objective here is depending on what city the user selected and then submits the form, it will be sent to an email address assigned to the value of that option. I have successfully been able to make this work on just simple form fields like "Name, email, and message". However since I have actually started creating the form and many more form fields it is no longer working. I have worked with a couple of tests, one using `print_r($_POST);`. After submitting the form it will display all of the form values that was sent, but not mail those results using `mail()` function. php code is below:

```
    <?php


//Sanatize field inputs

if(isset($_POST['post'])) {
    // check reCAPTCHA information
        require_once('recaptchalib.php');

        $privatekey = "6LcuhsgSAAAAAJ1Xlct4dmqOT2SnlhOuwAEImAXH ";
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
 // if CAPTCHA is correctly entered!                       
if ($resp->is_valid) {
            $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
            $headers = "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers = "subject: Application\r\n";
            $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        $cities = $_POST['cities'];               
        $lastname    = filter_var($_POST['lastname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
        $firstname  = filter_var($_POST['firstname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $middle = filter_var($_POST['middle'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $street = filter_var($_POST['street'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $city   = filter_var($_POST['city'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $state  = filter_var($_POST['state'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $zip    = filter_var($_POST['zip'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email   = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
        $hphone = filter_var($_POST['hphone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $cphone = filter_var($_POST['cphone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $social = filter_var($_POST['social'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $referral   = filter_var($_POST['referral'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $position   = filter_var($_POST['position'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $pay    = filter_var($_POST['pay'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);        

        $message = "
        New mail from:<br><br>
        Name: $firstname&nbsp;$lastname <br>
        Email: $email <br>
        Message: $position <br >
        $pay";
        //$to   = "testing@website.com";
            //Here I provide the email address for cities
        $email1 = "testin1g@website.com";
        $email2 = "testing2@website.com";
        $email3 = "testing3@website.com";
        //print_r($_POST);
            // Logic for getting the value of drop down and then sending mail.
        if ($cities == "NY"){
            $sendMail = mail($email1, $message, $headers);
                if($sendMail) {
                    echo 'Thank you ' .$firstname. ', the mail has been successfully sent!<br><br>';
                } else {
                     echo 'An error occured and the mail could not be sent.<br>
                    Please try again later.';
                }
        }
        elseif ($cities == "NC"){
            $sendMail = mail($email2, $message, $headers);
                if($sendMail) {
                    echo 'Thank you ' .$firstname. ', the mail has been successfully sent!<br><br>';
                } else {
                     echo 'An error occured and the mail could not be sent.<br>
                    Please try again later.';
                }
        } elseif ($cities == "TX"){
            $sendMail = mail($email3, $message, $headers);
            if($sendMail) {
                    echo 'Thank you ' .$firstname. ', the mail has been successfully sent!<br><br>';
                } else {
                     echo 'An error occured and the mail could not be sent.<br>
                    Please try again later.';
            }
        } elseif ($cities == "ME"){
            $sendMail = mail($email1, $message, $headers);
            if($sendMail) {
                    echo 'Thank you ' .$firstname. ', the mail has been successfully sent!<br><br>';
                } else {
                     echo 'An error occured and the mail could not be sent.<br>
                    Please try again later.';
            }
        }    
    } else {
        // handle the CAPTCHA being entered incorrectly
        echo 'You Did not enter the CAPTCHA in correctly. Please go back and do so.';
    }
}
session_destroy();  
?>
```

As you can see above I have a couple of email addresses listed and then using the if statement I am telling php if the "cities = state" to send to that email address. However this is the part it is getting hung up on. It is going straight to my error message.

And my html form:

```
<form method="post" action="../sendemail.php">

      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="900">
        <tr>

          <td width="800" bgcolor="White">

            <div id="copyContainerwide">
<h1>NexxLinx Career Opportunities</h1>
              <p>
               Thank you for your interest in a career with NexxLinx! We have many different opportunities for employment, which may vary depending 
               upon which center you are interested in applying for. For more information on what positions we have available, please contact your local
               NexxLinx centers, or visit us in person! </p>

 <br/>
 <p>To apply please select the center you would like to apply to:</p>

<select name="cities">
<option value="NY">Newburgh, NY</option>
<option value="NC">Jacksonville, NC</option>
<option value="TX" >Austin, TX</option>
<option value="ME">Orono, ME</option>
<option value="UT">South Jordan, UT</option>
</select>
<br/>
<p> TO THE APPLICANT: You must fully complete this application for it to be considered. Applications are active for ninety (90) days; 
              thereafter, you must personally renew the application to be considered for employment. We provide equal opportunities to all applicants 
              and employees without regard to race, color, religion, sex, national origin, age, or disability, in accordance with applicable federal 
              and state laws. Accommodation is available to applicants with a disabling condition, when applying, testing, or interviewing for a position.
              Please contact the Human Resource Department to request accommodation.</p>

 <fieldset>
 <legend>General Information </legend>
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name:<br/>
            <input name="lastname" type="text" size="30" /></td>
        <td> First Name:<br/>
            <input name="firstname" type="text" size="30"/></td>
        <td> Middle Name:<br/>
             <input name="middle" type="text" size="30"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Street Address<br/>
        <input name="street" type="text" size="50" /></td>
        <td> City<br/>
        <input name="city" type="text" size="30" /></td>
        <td>State (abbr.)<br/>
         <input name="state" type="text" size="7"  /></td>
        <td> Zip Code <br/>
        <input name="zip" type="text" size="12"  /></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     <table>
     <tr>
        <td>E-mail:<br/>
        <input name="email" type="email" size="50" /></td>
        <td>Home Phone:<br/>
        <input name="hphone" type="tel" size="15" /></td>
        <td>Cell Phone:<br/>
        <input name="cphone" type="tel" size="15" /></td>
        <td>Social Security Number<br/>
        <input name="social" type="text" size="12" /></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Referred By:</td>
        <td><input name="agency" type="checkbox" />Agency</td>
        <td><input name="advert" type="checkbox" />Advertisement</td>
        <td><input name="employee" type="checkbox" />Empoloyee</td>
        <td><input name="other" type="checkbox" />Other</td>
      </tr>
      <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Please list the name of the above agency, publication with the advertisement, employee, or other referall.<br/>
        <input name="referral" type="text" size="60" /></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
       <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Position Applied For:<br/>
        <input name="position" type="text" size="50"/></td>
        <td>Pay Desired:<br/>
        &#36;<input name="pay" type="text" size="20" /></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <?php
    require_once('../recaptchalib.php');
    $publickey = "6LcuhsgSAAAAAHtXF5i5f5XEAZmjyAtYvHGGQlhf ";
    echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="submit" name="post" value="submit" />
</table>
 </fieldset>
 </div>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

Thanks for any advice you can give me!

**UPDATE:**
Finally have this working! Thank you everyone for the help. For what ever reason and please correct if this is not right, I moved my headers up at the top of all of my other variables and it now works like a charm. FYI: I was working on this locally with WAMP and had a dumby sendmail configured to send through my gmail account. It work with very simple forms but apparently this one was a little too advanced, so I finally uploaded and finished testing it on my live server.

Something extra that maybe someone can help me with is validating a social security number and show the * when someone inters in numbers. Can that be done with javascript?

Comment: one issue that may be unrelated is that you start your if statements using `mail($email1, $message, $headers);` then on the next ones you switch to `$sendMail = mail($email2, $email, $headers);` - so you're using the `$email` instead of `$message` in all but one `mail()` calls

Comment: Ok, I will re-work that and see what that does. Thanks you.

Comment: additionally, your `mail()` function should use the following structure: `mail(to, subject, message, headers)`

Comment: is it already up?cause mail cant work in localhost thats the mistake i made when starting to learn mail function in php

Comment: I have mail() working on my localhost, but I had to do some extra configurations with sendmail and all of my testing gets sent through gmail. I am using wamp.

Comment: maybe your localhost setup is messing up the codes you might have fixed it now but will have an issue/error if you upload it so i suggest you upload it first then debug

Answer (score 0):

why not assign the email address to the value of the area if you can always reverse if your going to insert it in the database it like

```
<select name="cities">
<option value="test1@yahoo.com">Newburgh, NY</option>
<option value="test2@yahoo.com">Jacksonville, NC</option>
<option value="test3@yahoo.com" >Austin, TX</option>
</select>

$to=$_POST['cities'];

mail('$to', '$subject', '$message);
```

if you need to insert the location in database just reverse it

```
    if($citiies==test1@yahoo.com)
{
//insert into database NY
}
```

this code is shorter and looks cleaner but you will need to if else it again if your going to store the
location in the database

it will be shorter because you will not compare values just send it to what the value assign is

Comment: NO I am not using a database and that does seem more simplified, however what affect does that have with spam bots. Thanks

Comment: if you use this you will not be using if else just 1
 mail('$cities', '$subject', '$message); idk the issue of the spam bots but if you have a captcha i think that will filter it

Comment: it will be shorter because you will not compare values just send it to what the value assign to

Comment: Thanks Jose, however I am having no luck with that either. Still continues to go straight to my error message.

Comment: is it sending to mail somhow? or if you send it to a static mail for ex
mail('mymail@gmail.com', '$subject', '$message)
if that still doesnt work the bug is not in the mail function
and btw on your $message variable dont use <br> instead use \n or it will output <br> on your message and concatinate the variables inside it

Comment: Oh, I don't know about that. I will give that a try. Thanks.